# android check if bitmap is a valid image

Tags: java, android, image, bitmap, android-asynctask

I have created in Android an asynctask that gets an image from a link as a bitmap and displays it in an imageview

```
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import java.io.InputStream;

public class ImageViewLoader extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap>
{
    ImageView bmImage;
    public ImageViewLoader(ImageView bmImage)
    {
        this.bmImage = bmImage;
    }
    protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... urls)
    {
        String urldisplay = urls[0];
        Bitmap bitmap = null;
        try
        {
            InputStream in = new java.net.URL(urldisplay).openStream();
            bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return bitmap;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result)
    {
        bmImage.setImageBitmap(result);
    }
}
```

For example if I run this

```
ImageViewLoader loader=new ImageViewLoader(imageView);
loader.execute("http://localhost:8000/media/12");
```

I get this in the imageview

[image]

The image is successfully displayed but if somehow the image doesn't exist or there is a connection error I get an empty imageview and I would like to know how I can check if the returned bitmap from doInBackground is a valid image or not so that if not then I would set the imageview visibility to GONE

Comment: It would probably be easier to check if the image exists and there was no connection error, rather than check if the bmp is valid.

Comment: You do not have to set to GONE as a null bitmap will just force an empty imageview.

Comment: If the bitmap is not null than it is valid. Well if the server has a good image...

Comment: @greenapps you're right thanks